# Calling javascript without any action

Tags: javascript

i have the following lines of html code -

```
 <div class="twitters" id="cbd">
          <p><a href="javascript:;" onClick="tweeet('<?php echo $c; ?>')">My Tweets!</a></p>
        </div>
```

Now what i need to do is call the tweet() javascript function without any link being clicked or any button being clicked . i.e this function is called on its own whenever the page is loaded.

Comment: Note that your question has no relation to PHP language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you need this:

```
onClick="tweeet('<?php echo $c; ?>'); return false;"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `load` event which fires when page has loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    tweeet('<?php echo $c; ?>');
  };
</script>
```

Comment: that does not seem to be working. Actually for the correct working for the function it needs to be enclosed in those div tags whose class is "twitters"

Comment: @bobince: Good catch, I have become more used to jquery these days :)

Comment: @ayush: do you want to call tweet function for each div with class twitters?

Comment: @bobince,Sarfraz- thanks a lot. It had to be onload. working great now.

Comment: @Soe Moe - yes. thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a Javascript event to run from time to time, if you want to do that, this link will be helpful for you:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already solved the problem. I'm not sure, the question is not marked as answered.

That guy **sAc** answered your question. It can be called when the onload event is fired.

The function tweeet is probably just badly designed. It just doesn't make sense why would it needed to be enclosed in the div (especially when the div has its own id set).